# Token-based authentication for APIs: Speed up authentication between calls?

Tags: authentication, bcrypt

I currently have a token-based authentication system set up using bcrypt to encode the hash of my tokens in my db and to hash incoming tokens to check against what's in the db. I understand it's an advantage to have bcrypt have enough rounds of hashing that it takes some time to try new possibilities against it, but it's currently the bottleneck on my API when it gets many hits from one user. Is there any recommended way to make the authentication slow for a user the first time around, but once they've authenticated once to speed things up so they can get better throughput on their calls? Or maybe you guys have some other recommendations on compromises between security and speed in this sort of situation?

Comment: So you are using bcrypt on every API call, even if the user authenticated themselves correctly already? That wouldn’t make much sense.

Comment: @CBroe we're talking about an API where the user passes along their token with each call. I'm asking if there's a recommended secure way of not requiring them to keep doing that with every call. I can think of some off the top of my head, but because I'm not a security expert, and everyone warns to be very careful when coming up with your own cryptography ideas, I wanted to ask people who know more than me about it before going with anything.

Comment: Any reason why you can not use a simple session of sorts, once they have successfully authenticated …?

Comment: Wouldn't I need to encrypt whatever variable in the session makes it secret and then have the same issue?

Comment: No, you’d just need a random identifier for the session that no one else can “guess”.

Comment: @Eli Have you looked at [JWT](http://jwt.io)?